# Linear autocorrelation of maximum length sequence does not converge to Kronecker delta

Tags: numpy, scipy, correlation

[The linear autocorrelation of a Maximum Length Sequence approximates a Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence). This is also happening in scipy, for small lengths, e.g. n = 2**7:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.signal import max_len_seq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

seq = max_len_seq(7)[0]* 2 - 1
acorr = np.correlate(seq, seq, 'full')
plt.plot(acorr);
```

[image: n == 2**7]

But not for longer lengths, e.g. n=2**8

```
seq = max_len_seq(8)[0]* 2 - 1
acorr = np.correlate(seq, seq, 'full')
plt.plot(acorr);
```

[image: n == 2**8]

What is happening here? Is this a rounding problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Is this a rounding problem?"*

Sort of.  `seq.dtype` is `np.int8`, and when the input arrays of `correlate` have the same type, the array returned also has that data type.  So `acorr.dtype` is `np.int8`.  The problem is that the values in the true correlation calculation range from -18 to 255, and that range cannot be represented with `np.int8`.  The value of the spike, 255, "wraps around" to the value -1.  (I guess that makes it a wrap-arounding problem. :)

A fix is to convert `seq` to floating point, which can be done by making one of the coefficients in `seq = max_len_seq(8)[0]* 2 - 1` a floating point value.  E.g.

```
seq = max_len_seq(8)[0]* 2 - 1.0
```

Then `seq` (and therefore `acorr`) has data type `np.float64`, and the plot shows the expected spike.